# why does auto-boxing and unboxing of integers does not work with Arrays.asList in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, copy, autoboxing

The following is throws `compile error`:

```
int[] arrs = {1,2,4,3,5,6};
List<Integer> arry = Arrays.asList(arrs);
```

but this works:

```
for (Integer i : arrs){
   //do something
}
```

Auto-boxing works in many contexts, I just gave one example of `for-loop` above. but it fails in the `List-view` that I make in `Arrays.asList()`.

Why does this fail and why is such as a design implementation chosen?

Comment: Because there is no autoboxing for `int[]` to `Integer[]` and the method takes a `T[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make things work you need to use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

Argument of `asList` is of type `T...` and generic types `T` can't represent primitive types `int`, so it will represent most specific Object class, which in this case is array type `int[]`.
That is why `Arrays.asList(arrs);` will try to return `List<int[]>` instead of `List<int>` or even `List<Integer>`.

Some people expect automatic conversion from `int[]` to `Integer[]`, but lets nor forget that autoboxing works only for primitive types, but arrays are not primitive types.

Comment: Heh, nice edit, same answer now :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Arrays.asList` takes generic `T[]` as argument. This `T` is always an object, not a primitive. When you give an `int[]` as parameter (not an array of objects but primitives) it'll think the argument is actually the first element of the vararg. So the resulting list will have the fingerprint `List<int[]>` instead.

If you want to learn more about generics in Arrays, please read this page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/fineprint.html (part: Arrays)

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` takes a arbitrary number of arguments of given type **`T`** (`#asList(T.. t)`). Calling `Arrays.asList(arrs)` what you really do is passing single element of type `int[]` hence the problem.
It should be either:

`int[] arrs = {1,2,4,3,5,6};`
`List<int[]> arry = Arrays.asList(arrs);`

or

`List<Integer> arry = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);`